# Properly updating a ToolTip on a Control

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, label, tooltip

The only way I know to set a ToolTip is by creating a new ToolTip, and using `SetToolTip`. The problem is I don't know how to update it properly. If I do another `SetToolTip`, it adds another ToolTip. A few creations later, you'll notice a wave of ToolTips appear.

```
Dim tt As New ToolTip
tt.SetToolTip(ctrl, "W " & ctrl.Width & ", H " & ctrl.Height)
```

In this example, I've resized this panel quite a few times. On every resize, it sets the tooltip so you have an updated tooltip (of its width and height). Of course, this stacks tooltips on top of each other.

[image]

Comment: Are you using a `ToolTip` Compoenet?

Comment: I am using the ToolTip class to dynamically add and update ToolTip Text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you are setting the tooltip for your control using multiple instances of [`ToolTip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip(v=vs.110).aspx). So you see multiple tooltip for your control.

The `ToolTip` is an extender component and can extend multiple controls. So you can use one instance of `ToolTip` to set the tooltip text for multiple controls.

Put a `ToolTip` component on your form, and the you can set the tooltip text for a control using [`SetToolTip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.settooltip(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Me.ToolTip1.SetToolTip(Me.Label1, "ToolTip Text")
```

Also you can set the tooltip for the control at design-time using property grid. If you select the control that you want to set the tooltip for, the property will show as `ToolTip on ToolTip1`.

Comment: I didn't realize you could use one ToolTip object for multiple controls. I could initially create the ToolTip at design time, but that doesn't help much. All of the ToolTip text is changed at run time.

Comment: Tooltip is an extender component and adds the feature to multiple controls. So you can use just one instance.